# Orchestrating a Windows Azure web role to cope with occasional high workload

Tags: multithreading, azure, load-balancing

I'm running a Windows Azure web role which, on most days, receives very low traffic, but there are some (foreseeable) events which can lead to a high amount of background work which has to be done. The background work consists of many database calls (Azure SQL) and HTTP calls to external web services, so it is not really CPU-intensive, but it requires a lot of threads which are waiting for the database or the web service to answer. The background work is triggered by a normal HTTP request to the web role.

**I see two options to orchestrate this, and I'm not sure which one is better.**

- **Option 1, Threads:** When the request for the background work comes in, the web role starts as many threads as necessary (or queues the individual work items to the thread pool). In this option, I would configure a larger instance during the heavy workload, because these threads could require a lot of memory.
- **Option 2, Self-Invoking:** When the request for the background work comes in, the web role which receives it generates a HTTP request to itself for every item of background work. In this option, I could configure several web role instances, because the load balancer of Windows Azure balances the HTTP requests across the instances.

Option 1 is somewhat more straightforward, but it has the disadvantage that only one instance can process the background work. If I want more than one Azure instance to participate in the background work, I don't see any other option than sending HTTP requests from the role to itself, so that the load balancer can delegate some of the work to the other instances.

Maybe there are other options?

**EDIT:** Some more thoughts about option 2: When the request for the background work comes in, the instance that receives it would save the work to be done in some kind of queue (either Windows Azure Queues or some SQL table which works as a task queue). Then, it would generate a lot of HTTP requests to itself, so that the load balancer 'activates' all of the role instances. Each instance then dequeues a task from the queue and performs the task, then fetches the next task etc. until all tasks are done. It's like *occasionally using the web role as a worker role*.

I'm aware this approach has a smelly air (abusing web roles as worker roles, HTTP requests to the same web role), but I don't see the real disadvantages.

**EDIT 2:** I see that I should have elaborated a little bit more about the exact circumstances of the app:

The app needs to do some small tasks all the time. These tasks usually don't take more than 1-10 seconds, and they don't require a lot of CPU work. On normal days, we have only 50-100 tasks to be done, but on 'special days' (New Year is one of them), they could go into several 10'000 tasks which have to be done inside of a 1-2 hour window. The tasks are done in a web role, and we have a **Cron Job** which initiates the tasks **every minute**. So, every minute the web role receives a request to process new tasks, so it checks which tasks have to be processed, adds them to some sort of queue (currently it's an SQL table with an UPDATE with OUTPUT INSERTED, but we intend to switch to Azure Queues sometime). Currently, the same instance processes the tasks **immediately after queueing them**, but this won't scale, since the serial processing of several 10'000 tasks takes too long. That's the reason why we're looking for a **mechanism to broadcast the event "tasks are available" from the initial instance to the others.**

Comment: Quick clarification before I offer an answer... Re: "The background work is triggered by a normal HTTP request to the web role." What is the expectation regarding responding to this request -- does a the HTTP request simply trigger the (possibly lengthy) work, or is there some expectation the HTTP request will wait around for some sort of notification that the activity is complete? The answer to this question helps inform an overall strategy.

Comment: The HTTP request is simply there to trigger the lengthy work. It is currently done by a `wget [url] -O /dev/null` on a Unix server, which issues a simple HTTP request to the given URL and disposes of the response content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Gaurav and others to consider one of the Azure Queue options. This is really a convenient pattern for cleanly separating concerns while also smoothing out the load.

This basic Queue-Centric Workflow (QCW) pattern has the work request placed on a queue in the handling of the Web Role's HTTP request (the mechanism that triggers the work, apparently done via a cron job that invokes wget). Then the IIS web server in the Web Role goes on doing what it does best: handling HTTP requests. It does not require any support from a load balancer.

The Web Role needs to accept requests as fast as they come (then enqueues a message for each), but the dequeue part is a *pull* so the load can easily be tuned for available capacity (or capacity tuned for the load! this is the cloud!). You can choose to handle these one at a time, two at a time, or N at a time: whatever your testing (sizing exercise) tells you is the right fit for the size VM you deploy.

As you probably also are aware, the RoleEntryPoint::Run method on the Web Role can also be implemented to do work continually. The default implementation on the Web Role essentially just sleeps forever, but you could implement an infinite loop to query the queue to remove work and process it (and don't forget to Sleep whenever no messages are available from the queue! failure to do so will cause a money leak and may get you throttled). As Gaurav mentions, there are some other considerations in robustly implementing this QCW pattern (what happens if my node fails, or if there's a bad ("poison") message, bug in my code, etc.), but your use case does not seem overly concerned with this since the next kick from the cron job apparently would account for any (rare, but possible) failures in the infrastructure and perhaps assumes no fatal bugs (so you can't get stuck with poison messages), etc.

Decoupling placing items on the queue from processing items from the queue is really a logical design point. By this I mean you could change this at any time and move the processing side (the code pulling from the queue) to another application tier (a service tier) rather easily without breaking any part of the essential design. This gives a lot of flexibility. You could even run everything on a single Web Role node (or two if you need the SLA - not sure you do based on some of your comments) most of the time (two-tier), then go three-tier as needed by adding a bunch of processing VMs, such as for the New Year.

The number of processing nodes could also be adjusted dynamically based on signals from the environment - for example, if the queue length is growing or above some threshold, add more processing nodes. This is the cloud and this machinery can be fully automated.

**Now getting more speculative since I don't really know much about your app...**

By using the Run method mentioned earlier, you might be able to eliminate the cron job as well and do that work in that infinite loop; this depends on complexity of cron scheduling of course. Or you could also possibly even eliminate the entire Web tier (the Web Role) by having your cron job place work request items directly on the queue (perhaps using [one of the SDKs](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/overview/)). You still need code to process the requests, which could of course still be your Web Role, but at that point could just as easily use a Worker Role.

Comment: Never thought about implementing `RoleEntryPoint::Run` in a Web Role, gonna have a look at this. Thank you!

Comment: Implementing `RoleEntryPoint::Run` allows us to get rid of the Cron Job, so thanks for the suggestion. However, the problem of broadcasting between the instances (so that all instances begin to work on the background tasks) still remains, so we will try it with our **Option 2**.

Comment: With your Option 2 you can certainly spin up as many instances as you like to handle the load and they will just pull them from the queue. Any "extra" instances can be Worker Roles or Web Roles - all they need is a loop that checks the queue constantly: 
while (true) 
{ 
   var msg = <Get next message from queue(invisibility window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))>; 
   if (msg == null) {
      <Sleep for some number of seconds>; 
   }
   else { 
      <Process this message either inline or in a separate thread from the thread pool>; 
      <Delete message from queue>;   
   } 
}

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using Queues for distribution of work? You can put the "tasks" which needs to be processed in queue and then distribute the work to many worker processes.

The problem I see with approach 1 is that I see this as a "Scale Up" pattern and not "Scale Out" pattern. By deploying many small VM instances instead of one large instance will give you more scalability + availability IMHO. Furthermore you mentioned that your jobs are not CPU intensive. If you consider X-Small instance, for the cost of 1 Small instance ($0.12 / hour), you can deploy 6 X-Small instances ($0.02 / hour) and likewise for the cost of 1 Large instance ($0.48) you could deploy 24 X-Small instances.

Furthermore it's easy to scale in case of a "Scale Out" pattern as you just add or remove instances. In case of "Scale Up" (or "Scale Down") pattern since you're changing the VM Size, you would end up redeploying the package.

Sorry, if I went a bit tangential :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with you on the "Scale Up/Scale Out" advantage, but what do you think about option 2? Wouldn't that be a Scale Out approach? I did consider queues, but how can I use them in a web role without the help of additional worker roles? For example, if I have 4 web role instances, how can I make them all work on the queue simultaneously? The load balancer doesn't provide a way to influence the load balancing between the instances.

Comment: (Not knowing about your project) Since you mentioned the jobs are going to be background processes, I think worker roles are best suited for this approach. Possibly you could accept the request for the task through a web role and post it to a queue and let the worker role pick up the message. If I understand the 2nd scenario, you're trying to implement something what Windows Azure Queue does (and probably better). How do you envision supporting processing messages if during the message processing the instance goes down?

Comment: (if I could pay as many instances as I want, I would definitely go for worker roles, but at the moment I'm looking for options using only Web Roles) I edited the question and added some more details about the 2nd scenario. If one instance goes down during the message processing, the task would not be marked as complete and so another instance would soon process it. Of course I need some mechanism to prevent tasks from being processed twice.

Answer (score 2):

[Adding as a separate answer to avoid SO telling me to switch to chat mode + bypass comments length limitation] & thinking out loud :)

I see your point. Basically through HTTP request, you're kind of broadcasting the availability of a new task to be processed to other instances.

So if I understand correctly, when an instance receives request for the task to be processed, it pushes that request in some kind of queue (like you mentioned it could either be Windows Azure Queues [personally I would actually prefer that] or SQL Azure database [Not prefer that because you would have to implement your own message locking algorithm]) and then broadcast a message to all instances that some work needs to be done. Remaining instances (or may be the instance which is broadcasting it) can then see if they're free to process that task. One instance depending on its availability can then fetch the task from the queue and start processing that task.

Assuming you used Windows Azure Queues, when an instance fetched the message, it becomes unavailable to other instances immediately for some amount of time (visibility timeout period of Azure queues) thus avoiding duplicate processing of the task. If the task is processed successfully, the instance working on that task can delete the message.

If for some reason, the task is not processed, it will automatically reappear in the queue after visibility timeout period has expired. This however leads to another problem. Since your instances look for tasks based on a trigger (generating HTTP request) rather than polling, how will you ensure that all tasks get done? Assuming you get to process just one task and one task only and it fails since you didn't get a request to process the 2nd task, the 1st task will never get processed again. Obviously it won't happen in practical situation but something you might want to think about.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you, I see that I should have described some more details about the circumstances of the app. See my second edit. The last point you're making makes sense, but since the app will get a new request from the Cron Job the next minute, it's not a problem if one task gets 'forgotten', because it will just be processed when it has reappeared after the visible timeout, and when the next request is coming in from the Cron Job.

Answer (score 1):

i would definitely go for a scale out solution: less complex, more manageable and better in pricing. Plus you have a lesser risk on downtime in case of deployment failure (of course the mechanism of fault and upgrade domains should cover that, but nevertheless). so for that matter i completely back Gaurav on this one!